# How to call 'draw circle' from method to draw inside picturebox

Tags: c#, winforms

I don't know what to pass to my method to call my Circle drawing properly.
Here is my code:

```
    private void Circle()
    {
        Graphics g1 = e.Graphics;
        Pen p1 = new Pen(Color.Black);
        g1.DrawEllipse(p1, 12, 12, 50, 50);
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Circle();
    }
```

This is not working , cause there is no 'e'.

If i rewrite my code from

```
Graphics g1 = e.Graphics;
```

to

```
Graphics g1 = this.CreateGraphics();
```

It will draw circle but not in the picturebox. I need a circle to be inside picturebox.

Comment: you can pass 'e' as an argument

Answer (score 5):

If your method requires a reference to the `PaintEventArgs`, then why not supply it one?  Something like this:

```
private void Circle(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g1 = e.Graphics;
    Pen p1 = new Pen(Color.Black);
    g1.DrawEllipse(p1, 12, 12, 50, 50);
}

private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Circle(e);
}
```

This would allow other paint event handlers to make use of that method for their own controls as well.

Answer (score 1):

To get a reference to a `Graphics` object you can provide that via the parameters. Like

```
private void Circle(Graphics g)
{
    Pen p1 = new Pen(Color.Black);
    g.DrawEllipse(p1, 12, 12, 50, 50);
}

private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics myg = e.Graphics;
    Circle(myg);
}
```